# Error on "make get-monolite-latest" for Mono3

Tags: mono

I'm new to ubuntu and tying to install latest mono on ubuntu. When I issued the command

> `make get-monolite-latest`

but i got this error message

```
rm -fr /home/avalon/monobuild/mono/mcs/class/lib/monolite-* mkdir -p
    /home/avalon/monobuild/mono/mcs/class/lib test ! -d
    /home/avalon/monobuild/mono/mcs/class/lib/monolite || test ! -d
    /home/avalon/monobuild/mono/mcs/class/lib/monolite.old || rm -fr
    /home/avalon/monobuild/mono/mcs/class/lib/monolite.old test ! -d
    /home/avalon/monobuild/mono/mcs/class/lib/monolite || mv -f
    /home/avalon/monobuild/mono/mcs/class/lib/monolite
    /home/avalon/monobuild/mono/mcs/class/lib/monolite.old cd
    /home/avalon/monobuild/mono/mcs/class/lib && { (wget -O-
    http://storage.bos.xamarin.com/mono-dist-master/latest/monolite-110-latest.tar.gz
    || curl
    http://storage.bos.xamarin.com/mono-dist-master/latest/monolite-110-latest.tar.gz)
    | gzip -d | tar xf - ; }
        --2014-01-07 07:51:57--  http://storage.bos.xamarin.com/mono-dist-master/latest/monolite-110-latest.tar.gz
    Resolving storage.bos.xamarin.com (storage.bos.xamarin.com)...
        198.0.162.157 Connecting to storage.bos.xamarin.com (storage.bos.xamarin.com)|198.0.162.157|:80... connected. HTTP
    request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found 2014-01-07 07:51:59
    ERROR 404: Not Found.

        /bin/bash: curl: command not found

        gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file tar: This does not look like a tar archive tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous
    errors make:
        *** [get-monolite-latest] Error 2
```

Someone said the latest version of monolite is now 111 not 110 anymore
but i don't know how to apply the link changes to **"make get-monolite-latest"** command to install monolite compiler

Comment: Did you try downloading from the github repository:https://github.com/mono/mono/tree/mono-3.2.6-branch and then the instructions given below it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can override the URL with command line argument:

```
make monolite_url=http://storage.bos.xamarin.com/mono-dist-master/latest/monolite-111-latest.tar.gz get-monolite-latest
```

Comment: Btw I've found 110 still available at http://storage.bos.xamarin.com/mono-dist-master/bf/bf17a43b31a2be16f462ffdf1ae3d9801b846e90/monolite-110-latest.tar.gz

Comment: Looks like this url no longer works.

Answer (score 2):

Also note that in version 111, gmcs.exe was renamed to basic.exe

So run:

```
make EXTERNAL_MCS="${PWD}/mcs/class/lib/monolite/basic.exe"
```

Answer (score 0):

Me too have faced the same issue now. 
And found that url is down and changed to something else.

Solution is from make file I took this commands

```
cd $(mcslib) && { (wget -O- $(monolite_url) || curl $(monolite_url)) | gzip -d | tar xf - ; }
cd $(mcslib) && mv -f monolite-* monolite
```

I modified it and ran them on shell.
by replacing the $(mcslib) with the path of my mono source's mcs lib.
And $(monolite_url) with the correct url.

So in my case path was /home/ubuntu/softwares/mono

```
cd /home/ubuntu/softwares/mono/mcs/class/lib && { (wget -O- http://storage.bos.xamarin.com/mono-dist-master/latest/monolite-111-latest.tar.gz|| curl http://storage.bos.xamarin.com/mono-dist-master/latest/monolite-111-latest.tar.gz)| gzip -d | tar xf - ; } 
cd /home/ubuntu/softwares/mono/mcs/class/lib && mv -f monolite-* monolite
```

and then you can run

```
make EXTERNAL_MCS="${PWD}/mcs/class/lib/monolite/gmcs.exe"
```

hope this will solve your issue as well.